# new popup window on every click

Tags: javascript

I've a pop up window which i'm opening using below script. On every click, i want to open new pop up. 
I understand, having unique name for the window will solve the problem (In this case "SampleWindow"). 
What's the best way to maintain the uniqueness of the window ? Is there any other way to manage javascript popup ?

```
window.open(url, 'SampleWindow', 'WIDTH=300,HEIGHT=250');
```

Comment: Either of the below 3 answers would work.  It's preference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Passing a value of `_blank` to the `name` parameter will load the passed `URL` into a new window**. Like this:

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=300,height=250');
```

Other options for `name` parameter (*optional*) include:

- **`_blank`** - *URL is loaded into a new window. This is default*
- **`_parent`** - *URL is loaded into the parent frame*
- **`_self`** -   *URL replaces the current page*
- **`_top`** -    *URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded*
- **`name`** -    *The name of the window*

*Do note that if you'll be passing this JavaScript to an anchor tag `A` that IE browsers expect a return value, otherwise it'll referrence the `A` tag itself. Your code for that would look like:*

```
<a href="javascript:var w=window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=300,height=250');">test</a>
```

*or better (to avoid showing users your code in the status bar):*

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=300,height=250');">test</a>
```

---

Links:

- ***[window open() method reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)***
- ***[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AuLJ/)***

Answer (score 2):

You can append timestamp to your window name to create truly unique window names and assign that to variable. as...

`var myWindow = window.open(url, 'SampleWindow'+new Date().getTime(), 'WIDTH=300,HEIGHT=250');`

Since you want more than windows then it will be better to manage the windows through array.

```
var myWindow = [];
myWindow.push(window.open(url, 'SampleWindow'+new Date().getTime(), 'WIDTH=300,HEIGHT=250'));
```

These windows can be managed by `myWindow[index]` like `myWindow[2].close();`.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly just change the name each time

```
var i = 0;
window.open(url, 'SampleWindow' + i, 'WIDTH=300,HEIGHT=250');
i++;
```