# How to get popup on button click using anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get a popup on  clicking the anchor tag .And also I want the background to hide or blur.

*This is My code :*

```
<a class="button fifteen"><strong>Visit Our Website</strong></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try as below: ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714875/new-popup-window-on-every-click))

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=300,height=250');">test</a>
```

for the functionality to click working in popup , try as below:

```
<a href="yourLink"  target="popup"  onclick="window.open('yourLink','popup','width=600,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no'); return false;">
    Open Popup
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you'll get a popup.

```html
<a class="button fifteen" onclick="alert('hello!');return false;"><strong>Visit Our Website</strong></a>
```

Probably not what you need, try to be more specific in your question.

Comment: You're almost there, but i want two buttons `button1`, `button2` inside the alert box instead of `hello`. When on-clicking the the button1, it would redirect to link 1 and on clicking the button2 it must redirect to another page.

Comment: if you want  alert then i will give you custom alert so you want alert or popup ? @ ivin

Comment: @ivinraj you cannot put html inside a default js alert(or dialog or confirm) pop up. you will have to make a custom one, or use a library.